# Sqlite dump outputting tables out of order

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I'm trying to convert a Sqlite3 database to Postgres by dumping it to raw SQL, editing the SQL and then loading it via `psql`, summarized by [this script](https://gist.github.com/eclubb/2253099).

The overall approach seems fine, except for one problem. When I try to run the final load with `psql`, I get errors like "table x does not exist", because Sqlite is outputting tables referred to by foreign keys after the tables that refer to them. This causes psql to abort all further statements with the message:

```
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

The only immediately solution I see is to manually go through all the SQL and try to manually reorder the `CREATE TABLE` commands so that the proper order is maintained. However, this is very tedious.

Is there any way to force Sqlite to output SQL so that tables are output in order of dependency?